# Maths in C/C++ - Rounding Query

Tags: c++, c, math

Ok, so for a program I need to know two facts, the length of input and which highest number this length is closest to that is divisible by 4.
For example.
If the length is 1, I want to record 4.
If the length is 3, I want to record 4.
If the length is 5, I want to record 8.

Mathematically I can divide the length by 4, this gives a decimal. If I round it up and times by 4 it gives me the answer I need.
So, how do I get C to round up the contents of an int? I may be overcomplicating this so please say if I have missed something simple to do this.

Edit: I should add, I already know the length, this is something I would enter myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(length+3)/4*4`

Comment: Surely this is just a circle?
Add 3 to 4, get 7. Divide by 4. Then times by 4?

Comment: integer divide rounds down, so this ends up doing what you want (7/4 = 1)

Comment: Exactly what Chris said - an int divided by an int is an int (with the fractional part cut off.)

Comment: Thank you! Thats the beauty of this site, you learn things you should know and learn to trust the advice given.

Answer (score 4):

Overly-clever answer taking advantage of the fact that `4` is a power of two:

```
long rounded = length + 3 & -4UL;
```

Comment: +1, but I'd like to see the sum in parentheses even if technically not necessary. Without them it's too clever :)

Comment: @Maciej: I'm trying to teach the readers of SO operator precedence one post at a time!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I may give this a try at some point just to try and understand the maths! for now I have a working simple solution :)

Comment: @CashCow: It is not.  The mask is `-4`, which is the same as the `~3` in your answer.

Comment: Yes you are right I see now, it was late and my eyes were failing me

Comment: -1 The binary representation of -4 is implementation-defined.

Comment: @starblue: the representation of *signed* integers is implementation-defined.  The representation of *unsigned* integers (and the behavior of conversions from signed to unsigned integers), however, is specified by the standard.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: You're right, I looked it up. The code is sufficiently nasty that I don't regret the -1 though.

Comment: @starblue: In my defense, I did say that it was "overly clever" =)

Answer (score 2):

```
(i + (4 - (i % 4)) % 4)
```

See http://ideone.com/zZ181 for a demonstration

Answer (score 2):

The most intuitive answer given this is a power of 2 is `(length+3) & ~3`

(not ~4 as a previous answer suggested. We mask out the 1 and 2 bits having added 3).